# kind of equipment used in this video

Tags: camera

In the attached video, the camera films the crowd from above. How is this achieved? What kind of equipment is the camera equipped with?

Comment: I don't know, maybe a [wescam](http://www.wescam.com/)? Something tells me this isn't really a relevant question, although I'm sure someone could guesstimate a rig setup.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is this strange second camera?](http://video.stackexchange.com/questions/7131/what-is-this-strange-second-camera)

Answer (score 2):

As Jared said, probably not the most relevant question. But if I wanted to get a simmilar kind of shot I'd put a [GoPro](http://gopro.com/) on a [boom pole](https://encrypted.google.com/#hl=en&gs_nf=1&cp=8&gs_id=w&xhr=t&q=boom+pole&pf=p&output=search&sclient=psy-ab&oq=boom+pol&aq=0&aqi=g4&aql=&gs_l=&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=11b35ad57e24ec16&biw=1312&bih=929).

Comment: yep. its just a wide angle lense. a gopro would've looked better though, no black matting on the corners (although some people like that effect).